# XPath location if parent contains

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Struggling a bit trying to figure out what's going on with my XPath syntax here. Trying to locate an element to click based on the text of the parent.

I want to rotate through `<tr>` tags and and click a button if that tr contains specific text.

I've tried:

```
element = WebDriver.find_elements_by_xpath("//tr[contains(text(), 'This Text')]/td[@class='cell-to-click']")
```

Common stuff is all covered. The details are correct and loaded on the WebDriver etc... I can read the data parsing with BeautifulSoup so it is there. Just struggling to locate it to click.

I'd appreciate any pointers on this I'm out of things to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `//tr[contains(., 'This Text')]/td[@class='cell-to-click']` instead. `tr` elements usually don't have text nodes as children.

Comment: Perfect I hadn't though of that. Thank you!

Comment: Though if anyone knows how to substitute a string into here I'd appreciate it. My usual understanding of using %s doesn't seem to be cutting it >_< http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40616706/python-xpath-contains-s-in-selenium