# Python Xpath Contains %s in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I know this must be really, really simple but I can't quite figure out the syntax for this. I thought I understood but apparently I don't.

The XPath here works and if I use 'Wednesday' instead of '%s' it works fine but I'm trying to feed the XPath a variable string with this:

```
texttolookfor = "Wednesday"    
buttonelement= webDriver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[contains(., '%s')]/td[@class='button-cell']" % texttolookfor)
```

Which gives me:

```
<class 'selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException'>
```

But this works:

```
buttonelement= webDriver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr[contains(., 'Wednesday')]/td[@class='button-cell']")
```

So I've clearly misunderstood or made a mistake feeding the string in. I've been trying variations and looking at sample code but as far as my understanding goes this should of worked. I'd appreciate it if anyone could shed some light.

As asked in the comments I ran:

```
print "//tr[contains(., '%s')]/td[@class='button-cell']" % texttolookfor
```

which produced:

```
//tr[contains(., ' Wednesday')]/td[@class='button-cell']
```

Comment: If you're using a good XPath library, it'll let you pass variables out-of-band. Substituting data into code (and queries are code) is the source of all evil^W^Wmany security bugs.

Comment: so, typically, this would like like: `xpath("//tr[contains(., $string)]...", string=texttolookfor)`. *If* your library supports it, and I have no idea about Selenium.

Comment: That said -- if the library you're using *doesn't* support doing things the right way, might I suggest you store your substituted query in a variable, and print/log the variable?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with that: we use it in our production automation: `find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='organization']/option[text()='%s']" % organization)` without any issues

Comment: @TemporalWolf That you (representative for many developers) don't see anything wrong with that is the reason why XSS and code injection is such a widespread form of attack. Doing this provides an attack vector for an injection attack unless you make sure that `organization` does not contain any quotes (which reduces the usability of the whole thing). It's not something to take lightly, because a single slip-up in the wrong location can screw you up badly.

Comment: @Tomalak as an internal testing framework with hard-coded values, in our use-case, the security implications are not relevant.
What I meant was "it works for me." I wasn't dismissing the security concerns.

Comment: Yeah, i know the drill. Beginners generally don't, and I've seen enough seasoned programmers brushing it aside as "this can never happen, so why bother" - until it does, because some circumstances have changed and the whole thing blows up. If there is any way to not be sloppy, this is an area where I would say to never be sloppy even in benign circumstances.

Comment: Are you sure you always find the element in the second case and always get `NoSuchElementException` in the first, consistently? Thanks.

Comment: Security concerns are not really an issue in this case it is in-house but hard coding that text isn't really an option I don't know how else to use a variable. @alecxe the second example with hard coded text consistently works the first with the variable consistently gives NoSuchElementException.

Comment: can you please verify whether the value is being replaced correctly by adding print statement as follows: "print "//tr[contains(., '%s')]/td[@class='button-cell']" % texttolookfor"

Comment: Prints as expected:  //tr[contains(., ' Wednesday')]/td[@class='button-cell']

Comment: @PoweredByCoffee, in the value printed, I can see space before the word, like,  " Wednesday". Is it a typo? or the actual issue?